# Counting ones from txt file

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to solve an exercise: I have a txt file with images (20 rows x 20 columns) of 0's and 1's made random. Between each image (20x20) there is a gap of one empty line.

Based on this txt file I have to calculate how many of these images have more 1's than 0's. At the end I need to also find the highest number of 1's occuring in one image.

Here is my code so far ... but I am a little bit lost

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File input = new File("path to my txt file");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path to my txt file"));

        int counter = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            String word1 = scanner.next();
            String word2 = scanner.next();
            boolean switcher = false;


        int howManyOnes ("//path to my image file????") {
            int ones = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                    ones +=?[i][j];
                }
            }
            return ones;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to have written a method in a method. This doesn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding on which I will base my answer.

Your input is a text file in which each non-blank line has a total of 20 characters some of which are '1' and some of which are '0'.

An "image" is a collection of sequential non-blank lines. When one blank line is present it signals the end of one "image" and the beginning of the next "image".

**Your objectives are:**

> to calculate how many of these images have more 1's than 0's.

and

> find the highest number of 1's occurring in one image.

As this appears to be a homework type of question I will give you some guidance regarding how to design your code first and later if you're still struggling I can provide additional details. Please see [how to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

**Assumptions**:

1. You are allowed to use any of the methods of the `String` class.

Consider the things you want to track and in what scope you want to keep track of them. You need to be able to identify when an image begins and ends and track how many 1s and 0s you see within that image. That is, when an image begins the number of 1s and number of 0s for that image should be zero and you should increment them as you identify them in each line of the image. Once the image has been processed you will need to reset these to 0 to get ready to process the next image.

At the same time when you're done processing a single image you need to determine if the number of 1s in that image is greater than the number of 1s you've seen in any other image so far and if it is track that value. This value's scope is larger than the values mentioned previously as it is determined by the number of 1s in **all** of the images. It must **NOT** be reset with each image. Similarly, the number of images that have more 1s than 0s also has this kind of scope - it should **NOT** be reset with each image, rather it should be maintained until the entire file has been processed.

Next, consider how you can determine the number of 1s and 0s within an image. It looks like you're thinking about looping through every character and you could do it that way but there is a simpler way and it has to do with the assumption I mentioned.

I hope this gets you started. Please update your question as you write more code and I'll be happy to update my answer as well.